# span is not properly displayed in opera

Tags: css, opera

the spans .cursor and .cursorinner aren't displayed in opera, is there an opera specific css property I could set? is my css invalid or is this an opera bug?

i just tested this with different browsers, works in

```
ie 7-9
chrome
safari
firefox
```

doesn't work in opera tho

fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/etj6z/1/

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me in chrome.  I think you want `:first-child` and not `:first`

Comment: which chrome version are you using? i'm on Version 22.0.1229.79 m and can see the cursor, i had a look at http://jsfiddle.net/etj6z/2/ makes no difference for me.
btw i'm on windows 7

Comment: n/m, I was looking for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because you're depending on 2 inline elements to have defined block dimensions.  Adding `display: inline-block;` (or `display: block;`) to the cursor spans make the element display in Opera.  There is an additional issue with the blinking, which is due to the same issue.  You'd probably be better off using `show()` and `hide()` but otherwise you should be using `display: [inline-]block;` in the js also.

Comment: ahh, well i just saw that the cursor was displayed but in the wrong line, adding display: inline-block; gives me at least the same result across all browsers.

how could i improve my css to have the cursor at the bottom of the line?

Comment: ok i will go with it and just set bottom of .cursorinner to -4px or something so it fits in the line, if you have a better idea i would appreciate it to hear :)

Comment: At a glance it looks like doing it a more structured way wouldn't be worth the effort, so the quick -4px approach is probably a good a solution as any.